# changing the width of the element according to screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have provided a defined width for the parent here i.e '30%' and that parent is a sidenav of a jquery library. I want to change its width according to the screen size of device with onClick event using javascript like '100%' on less than 600px width and '30%' on above 600px width. I already tried using css media query but the css property are overridden by javascript. Please help how to do it.

```js
 $('.menu-list a').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var hide = $(this).data("hide");

     if (hide == true) {
         $(this).parent().parent().animate({
             width: '30%'
         }, 800);
         $('#mobile li').css('display', 'none');
         $('#mobile .close').css('display', 'block');
         $('#mobile .user-logo').css('display', 'none');
     } else {
         $(this).parent().parent().animate({
             width: '30%'
         }, 800);
         $('#mobile li').css('display', 'none');
         $('#mobile .close').css('display', 'block');
         $('#mobile .user-logo').css('display', 'block');
         $('#mobile .user-logo #edit-btn').css('display', 'inline-block');
     }

     var url = $(this).attr('href');
     $.ajax({
         url: url,
         beforeSend: function (data) {
             $('#content-here').html(loader);
         },
         dataType: 'html',
         success: function (data) {
             setTimeout(function () {
                 $('#content-here').html(data);
             }, 1000);
         }
     });

     $('#mobile #content-here').css('display', 'block');
 });
```

Comment: Your code and your description doesn't match... and it seems that you already got your answer (css @media query)...

Comment: Actually the parent which I am stating is a sidenav from a jquery library and it has its own defined width and I can't change it from CSS. Therefore, I need to do it from javascript. I want to change that '30%' according to the screen size using if..else condition but I am out of idea how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you can find windows width by using this jquery function:
$(window).width();
and your code be like:

```
if($(window).width() > 600){ 
//make sidenav 30% 
}
if($(window).width() < 600){
//make sidenav 100%
}
```

and simply you can paste this code inside click event. first you have to cache the width inside click event,so that width will be calculated each time you click the button.
Hope you understand the logic.

Answer (score 4):

CSS media queries would be an easier solution there.

```
element{
  width:30%;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  element {
    width:100%
  }
}
```

If you still want to use the jQuery:

```
$("yourElement").css({"width":"30%"});
if(screen.width<"600") $("yourElement").css({"width":"100%"});
```

Comment: I can't use media query here. That parent takes width from jquery library so I need a jquery solution. Appreciate your answer. Thank You.

Comment: @Ashish "That parent takes width from jquery library" - how does it force you not to use media queries?

Comment: because property I provide using CSS will be override by javascript. I already tried using media query and it didn't work.

Comment: @Ashish Doesn't make much sense. So the width of `element` is overriden with javascript? How could that be true, and why would you need it? You have mentioned that only parent of `element` takes the width from jQuery.

Comment: Actually the parent which I am stating is a sidenav from a jquery library and it has its own defined width and I can't change it from CSS. Therefore, I need to do it from javascript. I want to change that '30%' according to the screen size using if..else condition but I am out of idea how to do it.

Comment: @Ashish Oh - ok. Edited.

Comment: What's wrong with my answer that would require downvoting it?

Comment: @AshishPoudyal Are you there? If my answer worked, could you accept it please (click the checkmark)?

Comment: No, it did not work so I'm searching for other solutions. Thanks for your answer. I appreciate it. :)

Comment: @Ashish How so? What problem have you got with my code?

Comment: Your code is correct but its not the solution for what I'm searching. Thats all.

Comment: @Ashish There must be some reason why you don't want to use my code.

Comment: Hey I found the solution. Thanks for you answer and time. Good Luck